# Updating a PostgreSQL table from a CSV file

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, foreign-data-wrapper, postgres-fdw

I am trying to find a way to automatically update data from a csv file on a PostgreSQL table.

The csv file holds LabVIEW test data, which will renew with every execution and is stored on the local computer.

So far I am able to import data from the csv into table 'test1' using 2 methods:

1. COPY command

   ```
   COPY test1 FROM 'C:\Users\..\Test.csv' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV;
   ```
2. Foreign Data Wrappers (file_fdw)

   ```
   CREATE SERVER labview FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

   CREATE FOREIGN TABLE labview_test (
   column1 text
   )
   SERVER labview OPTIONS (filename 'C:\Users\..\Test.csv', format 'csv');
   ```

From there I can insert data into test1 using

```
    INSERT INTO test1 (column1) FROM labview_test;
```

This is ok for a single update, but I need this process to be automated. I tried using triggers and trigger functions and I am able to create the trigger on the foreign table, but the table does not update when I run a new LabVIEW test.

```
   CREATE FUNCTION copy_test ()
   RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (NEW.column1);
   RETURN NULL;
   END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


   CREATE TRIGGER copy_trigger
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON labview_test
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE copy_test ();
```

I read on a forum post that file_fdw does not support the trigger function, can anyone confirm this in the latest version of PostgreSQL (9.6)?

Does anyone know of a way to automatically update tables from a foreign table or from the .csv file directly?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a trigger on a foreign table, but....

You can create a materialized view of a foreign table. You can then put a trigger on the materialized view. Finally you can have an external scheduler refresh the materialized view (concurrently with data) and that should cause the trigger to fire on new data .

Comment: As of postgresql 9.4 you can have triggers on foreign tables https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-trigger-foreign-tables/

Comment: Sam, thanks for the clarification. This looks like a fantastic feature in 9.4 and onward. I’m looking forward to trying it out .